# How to make x^0 be 1 as x->0 in a power series?

Tags: summation

I'm trying to so this:

```
s[x_] := Sum[a[j]*Sum[a[k]*k*x^(k - 1), {k, 1, Infinity}]^j, {j, 1, Infinity}];
s[0]
```

It returns a 0^0 indeterminacy warning.  But a human working this problem on paper would get a[1] for the inner Sum at x=0 and therefore

$$s(0)=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } a(j) a(k)^j$$

I was hoping to get MMa to produce a power series on s[x], but we didn't get past s[0].

Ideas?

Comment: The error is eliminated when you change the range of the $k$ iterator to be $2$ to $\infty$, to avoid the $a^0$ term.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Yes, that will help with the first term, but it doesn't help with the derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Make the replacement x -> 0 after evaulation.

Let, with finite nn,

```
s[x_, nn_] := 
  Sum[a[j]*Sum[a[k]*k*x^(k - 1), {k, 1, nn}]^j, {j, 1, nn}];
```

Then, instead of writing s[0,nn], write

```
s[x, 4] /. x -> 0

(*
Out[49]= a[1]^2 + a[1]^2 a[2] + a[1]^3 a[3] + a[1]^4 a[4]
*)
```

Similarly for derivatives

```
D[s[x, 4], x] /. x -> 0

(*
Out[50]= 2 a[1] a[2] + 4 a[1] a[2]^2 + 6 a[1]^2 a[2] a[3] + 
 8 a[1]^3 a[2] a[4]
*)
```

and so on.

A compact form of the m-th derivative of our function (including the function itself for m = 0) is

s1[m_, y_, nn_] := 
  D[Sum[a[j]*Sum[a[k]*k*x^(k - 1), {k, 1, nn}]^j, {j, 1, nn}], {x, 
     m}] /. x -> y;

Examples

```
s1[0, x, 4]

(*
Out[73]= a[1] (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4]) + 
 a[2] (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4])^2 + 
 a[3] (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4])^3 + 
 a[4] (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4])^4
*)

s1[0, 0, 4]

(* 
Out[75]= a[1]^2 + a[1]^2 a[2] + a[1]^3 a[3] + a[1]^4 a[4] 
*)

s1[1, x, 4]

(*
Out[74]= a[1] (2 a[2] + 6 x a[3] + 12 x^2 a[4]) + 
 2 a[2] (2 a[2] + 6 x a[3] + 12 x^2 a[4]) (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 
    3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4]) + 
 3 a[3] (2 a[2] + 6 x a[3] + 12 x^2 a[4]) (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 
    3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4])^2 + 
 4 a[4] (2 a[2] + 6 x a[3] + 12 x^2 a[4]) (a[1] + 2 x a[2] + 
    3 x^2 a[3] + 4 x^3 a[4])^3
*)

s1[1, 0, 4]

(*
Out[76]= 2 a[1] a[2] + 4 a[1] a[2]^2 + 6 a[1]^2 a[2] a[3] + 
 8 a[1]^3 a[2] a[4]
*)
```

Comment: Nope, that did not work.

Comment: @ Jerry Guern: you are right. I have changed my answer. Now it works with your expression. Hope it helps.

Comment: Crude but effective.  I was hoping for some way to leave the sum in Summation form, though, because the expanded results gets unwieldy quickly.